# Flickr.NET - Bypass Flickr Authorization Page

Tags: flickr

I am uploading photos to Flickr in .NET project using Flickr.NET API Library ([Flickr.NET CodePlex Link](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/)). Its working perfect. But for every request, Flickr asks my permission to authorize the app (check screenshot below):

[image]

My question: is there any way I authorize the app once for my whole life rather it asks for my permission for each photo to upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have [exchanged your request token for an access token](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html#access_token), you can store the access token in your application's persistent memory and use the access token to make subsequent requests.

Comment: I was thinking this will be of application scope; As far as application is live and if, for any reason, application is restarted (stopped/crashed/broken), I need to get a new access token. But I was wrongly perceived that and just checked the same access token works in this case too. So the conclusion is, I need to get the access token once in the life time.